# Extracting texts after commands using regex

Tags: java, regex

I have a text like this

```
Hello. @b this is text 1 #u user1
```

I want to use regular expression to extract

```
This is text 1
user1
```

My first attempt is detecting @,# signs then recording those texts into a StringBuilder. However, this is an EditText, user can remove some characters and I had to remove it from the stringbuilder. Finally, it's getting more complicated so I decided to find another solution.

My question is: How can I extract those texts when a command(@b, #u, #b, @u) is available?
E.g:

```
Hello. @b this is text 1 => [This is text 1]
Hello. @b this is text 1 #u user1 => [This is text 1] [user1]
Hello. @u user1 => [user1]
```

My second attempt:

```
 Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("@b (.+) #u (.+)");
 Matcher mat = pattern.matcher(charSequence);
 while (mat.find()) {
      Logger.write("Matcher "+mat.group(1));
 }
```

But it only works in a specific case @b and #u

Comment: Why don't you apply your regexp each time, when user changes EditText's input?

Comment: yes,I'm using it when user changes input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That regex would be

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("(?<=[@#][bu]\\s)(?:(?![@#][bu]).)*");
```

**Explanation:**

```
(?<=    # Assert that this can be matched before the current position:
 [@#]   # an "@" or a "#"
 [bu]   # a "b" or a "u"
 \\s    # a whitespace character
)       # End of lookbehind assertion
(?:     # Then match...
 (?!    #  (as long as we're not at the start of the sequence
  [@#]  #  "@" or "#"
  [bu]  #  and "b" or "u"
 )      #  End of lookahead)
 .      # any character
)*      # any number of times
```

Comment: Thanks! I edited it a bit to make it fits my cases. But you gave me a very good explanation.
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("(?<=[@#][bu].)(?:(?![@#][bu]).)*");